# saveGIF() returns empty GIF

Tags: r, animation, imagemagick, gif

In R I am trying to get an animated GIF based on several images. I wrote a function returning the images and use the saveGIF() function of the animation package to create the GIF. The function returning the images works (I see the images popping up in the Viewer). When using saveGIF a GIF is created, there is no error message but the GIF is empty.

```
 library(leaflet)
 library(mapview)
 library(animation)

  latitude = c(seq(48.13608, 52.48608, 0.00145))
  longitude = c(seq(11.57278, 13.40278, 0.00061))

  sampledf <- as.data.frame(cbind(longitude, latitude))


  plot.1 <- function(df)
  {
  for (i in seq(1,nrow(df),300)){
  m<- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView( lng = 12.48778
           , lat = 50.31108
           , zoom = 4 )    %>%

  addPolylines(data = df[1:i,],
               lng = ~longitude,
               lat = ~latitude,
               color = ~"red")

  print(m)
 }
 }

  saveGIF(plot.1(sampledf),movie.name="test.gif", interval=0.5, ani.width=1980/2, ani.height=1080/2)
```

Comment: I don't know `leaflet`, but I would try `m` instead of `print(m)`.

Comment: @RonakShah, I added a sample df and the packages used

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I tried, did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a convoluted way to approach but I could do this by first creating `png` files for the `sampledf` data and then used `magick` library for producing gif's.

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(magick)

counter <- 1 
for (i in seq(1,nrow(sampledf),300)){

    m <- leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          setView( lng = 12.48778
                 , lat = 50.31108
                 , zoom = 4 )    %>%
           addPolylines(data = sampledf[1:i,],
                        lng = ~longitude,
                        lat = ~latitude,
                        color = ~"red")

     mapshot(m, file = paste0("plot_", counter, ".png"))
     counter = counter + 1
}
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "plot_\\d+.png$", full.names = TRUE)

image_read(file_names) %>%
   image_animate(fps = 1) %>%
   image_write("output.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: even though it might be a convoluted solution, it works perfectly, also integrated into the function. Thanks!